# Visual Studio 15 Preview 5 - Not working with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, c#-7.0

I have ReSharper 2016.2.2 installed onto Visual Studio "15" Preview 5.
When I use the new language features for C# 7.0 I get warnings that look like design-time errors, but my application compiles and runs fine.

I have also added this line to my Project's DotSettings file:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">Experimental</s:String>
```

I had understood this to be the correct setting for C# 7.0 ?

I would like to know if there is a setting/configuration that allows ReSharper 2016.2.2 to work correctly with Visual Studio "15" Preview 5.

Comment: Down-voted for a genuine question and no explanation why. I have been trolled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [latest EAP build for Resharper](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.3+EAP) to get support for Visual Studio 15 Preview builds and C# 7 features.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may be jumping the gun. The link [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/10/11/resharper-ultimate-2016-3-eap-whats-new-in-builds-2-and-3/) explains that C#7.0 support is still very much in the development stages and is not coming till version 2016.3 of ReSharper.